# Switch divs on click (prefer CSS but Jquery is ok too)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this has doing my head in for a couple of days now. I am trying to find a pure CSS solution for this but JQUERY is good as well. I would like to have a monthly price table by default on my page and switch the table with "Yearly" as soon as someone clicks on the link and vice versa..

**Here is the HTML mark-up:**

```
<div class="pricing_table" id="monthly">
   <ul>
     <li>Basic</li>
     <li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
   <h2>Monthly Plans</h2><a>Click here to switch to the "Yearly Plans"</a></ul>
</div>
<div class="pricing_table" id="yearly">
   <ul>
     <li>Basic</li>
     <li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
   <h2>Yearly Plans</h2><a>Click here to switch to the "Monthly Plans"</a></ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Here is a link to the solution http://jsfiddle.net/8TRAe/1/

Special Thanks to Tamil Vendhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML:

```
<div class="pricing_table" id="monthly">
<ul>
<li>Basic</li>
<li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
</ul>
<ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
<h2>Monthly Plans</h2><a class='plansSwitch' href='#yearly'>Click here to switch to the "Yearly Plans"</a></ul>
</div>
<div class="pricing_table" id="yearly">
<ul>
<li>Basic</li>
<li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
</ul>
<ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
<h2>Yearly Plans</h2><a class='plansSwitch' href='#monthly'>Click here to switch to the "Monthly Plans"</a></ul>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
var $plansHolders = $('#monthly, #yearly').hide();
$('#monthly').show();
$('.plansSwitch').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $plansHolders.hide();
  $(href).show();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29q3w/)**

Comment: The switch works but by default I'd like to display only "monthly" prices and hide the "yearly"

Comment: @MohammadMoezzi: Did you checked my fiddle, its exactly the same as you desire.

Comment: yes buddy the fiddle works like a charm but I don't know why both the tables appear on my website. when I am clicking on the monthly the switch works though.

Comment: ok, try this: replace `var $plansHolders = $('#monthly, #yearly').hide();
$('#monthly').show();` with `var $plansHolders = $('#monthly, #yearly').hide();
$('#monthly').show();
$('#yearly').hide()`

Comment: Actually, both are same. Are you sure that the `JS` is inside `$(document).ready(function() {/**JS code needs to be here **/})`?

Comment: Yes Tamil. maybe the jq function clashes with my other jq codes in the same page. let me try the code on a plain page. let you know. cheers

Comment: Here is the link to my source file on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webnerdoz/8TRAe/

Comment: You have not selected `jQuery` framework in you fiddle. I have updated it now. http://jsfiddle.net/8TRAe/1/. Works as expected.

Comment: Can you check the console of your site & post it here?

Comment: I am trying to cut and paste what you have done in the fiddle but ti is still not working on my website. sorry what do you mean by selected jquery framework?

Comment: You have not included `Jquery` in the test page. If you do it, everything will work as expected.

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` add it in the `head` block

Comment: You are awesome. thanks heaps. I will vote up your answer as soon as I get sufficient reputation. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Mohammad Moezzi: you can mark this answer as accepted if this answer does solve your problem

Comment: @MohammadMoezzi: Welcome man. No problems about the vote, I am glad that I am able to help a guy. Cheers

Comment: @KhanhTO like I said in my previous comment I don't have enough reputation for voting yet. maybe you can do it on my behalf :) cheers

Comment: @Mohammad Moezzi: you should know that there is a tick below the down arrow. Clicking on that will accept the answer and the answerer (in this case is Tamil Vendhan) will gain 15 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Assign ids to your links first

```
<a id="yearlyPlan">Click here to switch to the "Yearly Plans"</a>

<a  id="monthlyPlan">Click here to switch to the "Monthly Plans"</a>
```

Your JS:

```
$("#yearlyPlan").click(function(event) {
  $("#monthly").hide();
  $("#yearly").show();
});

$("#monthlyPlan").click(function(event) {
  $("#monthly").show();
  $("#yearly").hide();
});
```

> I would like to have a monthly price table by default on my page

To do that, set `style="display:none"` to yearly in your HTML

```
<div class="pricing_table" id="yearly" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be what you need:

**jQuery**:

```
$("#monthly a:not(.buy_now)").click(function(event) {
  $("#monthly").hide();
  $("#yearly").show();
});
```

Better, of course, to assign some class to "click here for yearly" link and filter by that instead of `:not()`

Answer (score 0):

easist will be giving a same class to both your link `<a>`..

using jquery,

```
$(function(){
 $('#yearly').hide();
 $('.aClass').click(function(){
   $('.pricing_table').hide();
   $(this).parents('.pricing_table').show();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example

HTML

```
<div class="pricing_table" id="monthly">
    <ul>
        <li>Basic</li>
        <li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
        <h2>Monthly Plans</h2><a href="#" id="yearly-link">Click here to switch to the "Yearly Plans"</a></ul>
</div>
<div class="pricing_table" id="yearly" style='display: none;'>
    <ul>
        <li>Basic</li>
        <li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
        <h2>Yearly Plans</h2><a href='#' id='monthly-link'>Click here to switch to the "Monthly Plans"</a></ul>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
$('#monthly-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#yearly').hide();
    $('#monthly').show();
});

$('#yearly-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#monthly').hide();
    $('#yearly').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS-only solution using radio buttons. Should work okay for IE9+.

http://jsfiddle.net/cyuEw/

#### CSS

```
input[type="radio"], #yearly + div, #monthly + div{
    display: none;
}

input:checked + div {
    display: block !important;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<input id="yearly" type="radio" name="toggle" checked>
<div class="pricing_table">
   <ul>
     <li>Basic</li>
     <li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
   <h2>Monthly Plans</h2><label for="monthly">Click here to switch to the "Yearly Plans"</label></ul>
</div>
<input id="monthly" type="radio" name="toggle">
<div class="pricing_table">
   <ul>
     <li>Basic</li>
     <li><a href="" class="buy_now">Subscribe Now</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul style="background-color:#CCCCCC;">
   <h2>Yearly Plans</h2><label for="yearly">Click here to switch to the "Monthly Plans"</label></ul>
</div>
```